# Cómo quitar filtros a una tabla escrapeada en R?

Tags: r

Tengo un Scrip en R que extrae datos de un portal web, desde la pagina la tabla tiene un filtro en una una columna que se llama "Intrumento", quisiera eliminar el filtro que en la URL se ve asi "Tool = IAD% 20Software% 20I% 20-% 20Microsoft", quisiera quitar el filtro para ver el total de registros.

El script en R es así

library(rvest)

```
urls.colombia.compra <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")


base.colombia.compra <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table)

base.colombia.compra
```

Cómo puedo editar el código para eliminar el filtro y poder ver todos los registros?

Comment: Entiendo que no puedes, o al menos si lo dejas en blanco deberías usar otro filtro ya que la página te exige que cargues algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que vi no se puede dejar en blanco o usar un comodín, así que no podrías quitar el filtro como tal. Sin embargo, dado que es un menú desplegable y tiene un conjunto predefinido de opciones lo se puede hacer es scrapear todos los posibles valores de "Instrumento" luego hacer un request con cada uno de ellos.

En tu caso usando el inspector de navegador encuentras que las opciones de "Instrumento" están listadas como un atributo `value`. En ese caso es cuestión de identificar la etiqueta que los contiene y luego escrapearlos.

Va una captura del inspector desde el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Va un ejemplo:

```
cruda <- read_html("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/?number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Elementos%20para%20Emergencias&date_to&date_from")

cruda %>% 
  html_elements(".form-select") %>%   #Esta es la clase a la que pertenecen esos valores
  html_elements("option") %>%         #Este es el identificador
  html_attr("value") -> instrumentos   #Este el atributo que te interesa
 
head(instrumentos[6:133])  #Comienzo en la ubicación 6 porque las 5 primeras son basura que quedó ahí. 

[1] "Acceso Banda Ancha Municipios"             "Acuerdos Marco de Precios"                
[3] "Adquisición de Computadores y Periféricos" "Almacenamiento PAE"                       
[5] "Almacenamiento PAE II"                     "Alquiler de ETP II"
```

Con el vector `instrumentos` puedes iterar (usando `map` u otro) por cada búsqueda, es cuestión de armar la `url` correcta. Es lo mismo que hiciste para solucionar el problema del paginado. Algo así:

```
paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/?number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=", 
       instrumentos[6:133], 
       "&date_to&date_from")
```

Podrías también usar un procedimiento similar para resolver el problema del paginado buscando en cada página cuál es el último elemento.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!